# Flash & IE : “Object doesn’t support this property or method” error (using ExternalInterface)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

In my actionscript file I have:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("loadHotspotsXMLCallback", hotspotsXMLCallback);
```

In html I have:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" salign="" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="false" menu="false" name="FloorplanViewer" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="FloorplanViewer" devicefont="false" wmode="transparent" scale="showall" loop="false" play="true" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" flashvars="..." src="swf/FloorplanViewer_V110228b.swf">
```

In JS I have:

```
$("FloorplanViewer")["loadHotspotsXMLCallback"](response.responseText);
```

And I've also tried:

```
window["loadHotspotsXMLCallback"](response.responseText)
```

and

```
document["loadHotspotsXMLCallback"](response.responseText)
```

**But the JS part DNW in IE, and it does in FF and GC.
Does anybody know why?**

[I've read this documentation on using ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), and while my problem is occuring for IE8, I tried the follwing suggested IE7 solutions mentioned there:

- making sure that the added external callback name is not the same as the internal callback name for the actionscript code above.
- delaying the code that adds the callback by 500ms

But these changes had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest trying it as simple as possible from my article, http://work.arounds.org/issue/10/calling-flash-functions-from-javascript/

```
<object id="flash" data="file.swf" width="420" height="300"></object>
<script>
      onload = function() {
          var flash = document.getElementById('flash');
          flash.NextFrame();
      }
</script>
```

First try converting your `embed` to an `object`, then just a simple get element by ID after window load. Also try `alert( 'functionName' in flash );` to make sure the method exists.

Comment: the flash is added during `window.onload` so that can't be the prob

Comment: "Also try alert( 'functionName' in flash ); to make sure the method exists." the error is that is occurring on IE is saying that the property/method DNE.

Comment: @Erik Void - Did you try this method exactly? Do your methods use gEBI as mine does?

Comment: I did have to use `object` instead of `embed`, I took a close look at an example that worked and noticed some js if logic that used `object` for IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
var fpViewer = document["FloorplanViewer'] || window["FloorplanViewer"];
fpViewer.loadHotspotsXMLCallback(response.responseText);
```

Also, I lose track on what the best practice is for inserting Flash into pages nowadays. But I'd definitely wrap that `embed` element with an `object` element, to ensure maximum cross browser compatibility.

Rich

Comment: `var fpViewer = document["FloorplanViewer'] || window["FloorplanViewer"];` this is not working.

Comment: Have you added the object tag? The embed tag has limited browser support?

Answer (score 0):

> I had a really hard time solving problems like that with IE 6, 7, 8, etcs..

Some things that helped, in order of priority:

1. delaying the code that CALLS the callback
2. If you have more than 1 SWF using that, try not to attach all the SWF files that adds callbacks/etcs at the same time

Two or more concurrent javascript calls ( addCallbacks / ExternalInterface.call / etcs ) normally results in some IE fail.

If you need to do many javascript calls, may be is the case to implement a "Javascript call stack" that will call each operation after another one with a little delay.

#### really hope it helps

i had really bad times struggling with IE / cross-browser compatibility with more than 1 swf file in the same page needing control from/to javascript